# Assertion failed in OpenCV's calibrate camera

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do a camera calibration with OpenCV 2.4.9 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, but I always get this error:

```
Assertion failed (i < 0) in cv::_InputArray::getMat, file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdoc1\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 963
```

Here's my code for the calibration part:

```
m->srcLR.copyTo(webcamImage);
pyrUp(webcamImage, webcamImage);
cvtColor(webcamImage, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

bool found = findChessboardCorners(gray, cbSize, imagePoints, CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

if (found)
{
    cout << "found";
    cornerSubPix(gray, imagePoints, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1), TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
    drawChessboardCorners(webcamImage, Size(boardW, boardH), imagePoints, found);
}

if (waitKey(30) == char('c'))
{
    calibrateCamera(boardPoints, imagePoints, cbSize, intrinsics, distortion, rvecs, tvecs);
    cout << endl << intrinsics << endl;
    cout << endl << distortion << endl;
}

imshow("Calibrate Camera", webcamImage);
waitKey(10);
```

details about the data type:

- boardPoints -> vector of Point3d

  `for (int i=0; i<boardW; i++)
      {
          for (int j=0; j<boardH; j++)
          {
              boardPoints.push_back(Point3d(double(i), double(j), 0.0));
          }
      }`

with boardW = 9 and boardH = 6.

- imagePoints -> vector of Point2d
- intrinsics -> Mat, 3x3
- distortion -> Mat, 8x1
- rvecs -> vector of Mat
- tvecs -> vector of Mat

I commented the `cornerSubPix` and `drawChessboardCorners` because I intended to use it but it also get errors, and my main goals is the intrinsics and the distortion matrices.

**Additional information:** The error that I previously mentioned occured when I pressed the 'c' button. The other error happened in cornerSubPix and drawChessboardCorners:

cornersubpix:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ncorners >= 0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F) in cv::cornerSubPix, file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\cornersubpix.cpp, line 257
```

drawchessboardcorners:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nelems >= 0) in cv::drawChessboardCorners, file C:\buildslave64\win64_amdocl\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibinit.cpp, line 1939
```

Comment: Do you know at which line this error occurs? Does webCamImage contain any data?

Comment: @dev_nut so m is an object that contains the values of VideoCapture and its matrix, srcLR is the flipped matrix. I copied that to webcamImage so webcamImage contains the input from the webcam. The error happens when I pressed 'c' button, when the calibrateCamera function is called. Other than that is working fine.

Comment: Does the error occur before or after output of cout << endl << intrinsics << endl;
    cout << endl << distortion << endl;?

Comment: You need to give more information so that someone can help you (Paste the output of the program, write out the image webCamImage and gray using imwrite and show us what it looks like). You say it is working fine, but clearly if cornersSubPix and drawChessboardCorners are not working, that means something is wrong. Make sure you can get see the output image of drawChessboardCorners. There is no point calling calibrateCamera if those are failing.

Comment: Also, if you want to understand why it matters, have a look at this post - https://mackiemathew.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/list-of-issues-that-can-arise-with-3d-reconstruction-using-stereo-cameras/ ... Disclaimer - I wrote that.

Comment: @Micka cbSize is the size of the window; the error occured before the cout intrinsics lines. My console window printed out "found" and then the error message, so the problem is in my calibrateCamera function

Comment: @dev_nut I just added the error messages for the cornerSubPix and drawChessboardCorners function...